# Как на windows phone выполнить метод после события

Tags: c#, windowsphone

У меня есть событие которое выполняется при нажатии кнопки:

```
private void AnswerPressAction(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        Button validButton = null;
        string buttonName = button.Name;
        button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        int presedAnswer = 0;
        switch (buttonName)
        {
            case "buttonAnswer1":
                presedAnswer = 1;
                break;
            case "buttonAnswer2":
                presedAnswer = 2;
                break;
            case "buttonAnswer3":
                presedAnswer = 3;
                break;
            case "buttonAnswer4":
                presedAnswer = 4;
                break;
        }

        switch (_valid_answer)
        {
            case 1:
                validButton = buttonAnswer1;
                break;
            case 2:
                validButton = buttonAnswer2;
                break;
            case 3:
                validButton = buttonAnswer3;
                break;
            case 4:
                validButton = buttonAnswer4;
                break;
        }



        if (presedAnswer != 0 && presedAnswer == _valid_answer)
        {
            button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            _gameLevel++;
            CreateQuestion(_gameLevel);
        }
        else
        {
            button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            validButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            MainPage mp = new MainPage();
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?show_error=true", UriKind.Relative));
            _gameLevel = 0;
        }
    }
```

Проблема в том, что я не могу установить цвет кнопки на желаемый при событии, потому что пока событие выполняется, кнопка "нажата", а мне нужно манипулировать кнопкой во время метода.

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли способ передать управление другому методу, так что бы кнопка уже не была нажата, т.е. при завершении события.

Comment: вам надо поиграть с состояниями кнопки, если вы ее хотите перекрасить уже отжатую, то в событии перекрасите состояние `Normal`

Comment: в обработчике создайте отдельный Thread или Task. в нем, если надо что-то делать с кнопкой и другим UI, то используйте Dispatcher.Invoke(...)

Answer (score 3):

Кнопка - визуальный элемент. Управляйте её поведением через [триггеры xaml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.style.triggers(v=vs.110).aspx).

Могу предоставить более развёрнутый пример кода xaml, если опишете свою ситуацию.

Comment: Единственный адекватный ответ. Всем лишь бы в code-behind писать.

Answer (score 0):

Ваша задача решается с помощью асинхронного программирования с использованием async/await. Ваш код довольно просто переписывается в следующее:

```
private async void AnswerPressAction(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    Button validButton = null;
    string buttonName = button.Name;
    button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    int presedAnswer = 0;
    switch (buttonName)
    {
        case "buttonAnswer1":
            presedAnswer = 1;
            break;
        case "buttonAnswer2":
            presedAnswer = 2;
            break;
        case "buttonAnswer3":
            presedAnswer = 3;
            break;
        case "buttonAnswer4":
            presedAnswer = 4;
            break;
    }

    switch (_valid_answer)
    {
        case 1:
            validButton = buttonAnswer1;
            break;
        case 2:
            validButton = buttonAnswer2;
            break;
        case 3:
            validButton = buttonAnswer3;
            break;
        case 4:
            validButton = buttonAnswer4;
            break;
    }



    if (presedAnswer != 0 && presedAnswer == _valid_answer)
    {
        button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        _gameLevel++;
        CreateQuestion(_gameLevel);
    }
    else
    {
        button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        validButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        MainPage mp = new MainPage();
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?show_error=true", UriKind.Relative));
        _gameLevel = 0;
    }
}
```

Таким образом вы можете не только менять визуальное состояние элементов, но и вызывать другие асинхронные методы.

О том, что такое асинхронное программирование и как работает, можно прочитать [тут (Англ. яз.)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) и на [Хабрахабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/139734/)